# Como passar uma array nos atributos do HTML e não mostrar aspas simples?

Tags: php, html, array, atributos

Seguindo esse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something) Eu criei o seguinte html passando arrays como atributo de um elemento input:

```
...
<input type="text" name="setValues[cardExpiration]" id="card_expiry" class="input-small" value="1222">
<input type="text" name="setValues[ipAddress]" id="ip" value="24.37.246.194">
...
```

Depois que o formulário é submetido teremos o seguinte array multi dimensional dentro de `$_POST`:

[image]

Perceba com `var_dump()` as chaves do array interno:

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

[image]

Quando tentamos recuperar os valores isso é o que acontece:

```
$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["email"]:FALSE);//NULL

$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]:FALSE);//Retorna o e-mail preenchido no formulário
```

O ponto centra aqui é essa aspas simples **'** key **'** que está sendo criada dentro da chave do array.

É por isso que `$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]` funciona e `$_POST["setValues"]["email"]` não funciona, retorna NULL.

Então a minha pergunta é como poderíamos criar esse array dentro do atributo do input sem que apareça essas aspas simples na chave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei aqui e funciona sim normalmente.

Quando você envia um form dessa maneira:

```
            <div>
                    <label>Nome:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="form[nome]">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="form[email]">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Telefone/Whatsapp:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="form[telefone]">
                </div>
            </div>
```

O php irá receber normalmente:

```
var_dump($_POST["form"]["nome"]);

// irá exibir
string(87) "Quo molestias deserunt voluptas fuga Molestiae animi vel aliquip elit quam ipsum soluta"
```